# Lightning Layouts - how to activate it? is it available in Sandboxes?

Tags: lightning-experience, lightning-layouts

Seen this presentation of Lightning Layouts - https://www.salesforce.com/video/3632069/ .  (~25th min)

I can't find this in my sandbox, Winter 19 release.

How do I activate it?

Answer (score 1):

This is a presentation of future features of Salesforce..

See e.g. minute 35:30 - contact your account executive to apply for participation in one of these pilots.

[image]